# get the total value base on month

Tags: excel-2010

i'm trying to get the total of value bas on month like this.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MONTH($A$2:$A$10)=MONTH(C2);($B$2:$B$10))
have even try
=SUMPRODUCT(--(TEXT($A$1:$A$10,"yyyy-mm")=C2);$B$1:$B$10)
```

but all i get is Zero.

here is some sample

```
Column A         b            c           d              f       g

2012-10-02       45           2012-10     45             2012    229
2012-09-05       45           2012-09     100            ect.
2012-09-03       55           2012-08     84                      
2012-08-25       84           ect.
etc.
ect.
```

thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with Excel 2010, you have the power of `SUMIFS`.

I would rewrite the formula as:

```
=SUMIFS(B:B;A:A;">="&DATE(YEAR(C2),MONTH(C2),1);A:A;"<"&DATE(YEAR(C2),MONTH(C2)+1,1))
```

which translates to:

Sum column B if the column A value is equal to or greater than the 1st of the month in C2, **and** less than the 1st of the next month

looking at column **F**, the same formula for the year would be:

```
=SUMIFS(B:B;A:A;">="&DATE(E2,1,1);A:A;"<"&DATE(E2+1,1,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH($A$2:$A$10)=MONTH(C2));($B$2:$B$10))
```

But be sure that C is a date column (2012-10-xx). Es 2012-10-01.

Comment: thx! it's working now. but i when i add new row the  $A$2 change to $A$3 and $B$2 change to $B$3. can i some how make it stay on A2 all the time? thx

Comment: change the range refs to `$A$1:$A$10` and `$B$1:$B$10` Even if row 1 contains headers, so long as they arn't dates it won't matter.

Comment: Hi when i change to $A$1 and $B$1 as u said i got #value?